# addeventlistener - when to use parameters in the function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

(I'm new to coding)

I'm currently stuck on trying to understand when we need to use parameters inside the

```
userInput.AddEventListener('keyup',function(**event**) {
let username = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

this is the little piece of code however I do not understand when the use of the parameter is needed for it, if anyone can link the appropriate source where I can learn, it will be greatly appreciated.

Just to clarify I do not understand the logic behind function(event) or when is the parameter being used, when is appropriate to use it and so on.

Comment: When ever you will need one or more properties the event object contains. In your example code the DOM element fired the event (`event.target`) is used.

Comment: the `event` parameter represents a value which the browser passes into the callback function when it runs (obviously, it runs when the "keyup" event occurs on the input control). The event object contains various properties which provide information about the event which has occurred. You may occasionally need them, depending on what you want to do in the callback.

Comment: [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: Useful references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: And specifically: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_objects and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input, this clears out a lot of questions in my head, and thank you for the resources, I will use them to reinforce my understanding.

Comment: And for the keyup event, the event object complies with this interface: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Comment: You _can_ use `event` without passing it as a parameter due to it being [a global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), but you really shouldn't use it that way. Add it as a parameter when you use it, otherwise you may leave it out.